# ¿Donde son almacenadas las imágenes descargas con el comando wget?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, wget

Estoy intentando descarga una imagen con el siguiente comando:

```
$ wget <imagen_url>
```

la terminal me indica que la imagen fue descargada pero no encuentro el directorio de almacenamiento

Comment: En `pwd`. (Relleno de comentario)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el prompt dice la ruta donde te encuentras ***usuario@dominio:~$***, si tu prompt antes de **$** esta un **~** quiere decir que estas en la carpeta home de tu usuario ***(/home/usuario/***), si quieres saber específicamente la ruta donde te encuentras, ejecuta el comando **pwd** y te mostrará la ruta donde ejecutas el **wget** y ahi es donde se guardó tu descarga.

Answer (score 1):

En donde estés parado en ese momento, es decir en la ruta desde donde estés ejecutando el comando, ejemplo si estoy en mi home

```
/home/usuario/
```

Y ejecuto:

```
wget <imagen_url>
```

Se guardará en `/home/usuario/imagen_descargada.jgp`

Para saber donde estás ejecuta:

```
pwd
```

Answer (score 1):

A modo de completar un poco la respuesta a tu pregunta. En el caso de que quieras especificar tu mismo la ruta de descarga (mucho más cómodo) de la imagen que quieres obtener, deberías añadir al comando: `-P /ruta/deseada/`, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
wget <imagen_url> -P /home/usuario/descargas
```

Guardando la imagen en la carpeta **descargas**, creándola si no existe.